# Windows Vista Home Premium Wifi slow loading

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, connection

Windows Vista 32-bit Home Premium is slow to load and identify my home WI-FI network.  I have 4 bars, and have disabled all other connections, yet it still takes a long time to connect and have internet access?

Linksys WRT series router, Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card.

I have already cut down big time and monitor very closely every start-up program.  It takes a while to load the icon in the status bar, but once, I'm on, it is normal and fast...

Comment: This question is really hard to answer without seeing your computer setup or more information about what is installed on the computer. Is this something that happened just all of a sudden or has it always acted like this? Install any new software recently? What kind of router do you connect to? What kind of wifi card is in the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look and see if there are more current drivers for your wireless card. Updating your drivers could solve this issue - I had a similar problem while running Windows 7 RC with my built-in Dell wireless.

[Dell's Support Page](http://support.dell.com/support/index.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen)

Answer (score 2):

If you know how, try to set the connection properties manually.  If your connection is set to automatic, the computer usually requests a DHCP assigned IP address.

This means that every time it connects to the router, it requests what IP address it should have.  If you statically set this, it cuts down on connection times because the computer already knows what IP address it's going to use.

What you can try is viewing that your current settings, and set them statically in the network connection properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are judging the connection speed by how fast the little connected icon shows in your tray, please be aware that it will often be connected before that icon shows up.

The icon can be delayed by all the other stuff that is loading at the startup.

[Glary Utilties](http://download.cnet.com/Glary-Utilities/3000-2094_4-10508531.html?tag=mncol) and [CCleaner] have Startup Managers that will show you all the programs that are loading at startup.  Often there are many programs loading that aren't necessary that result in long loading times.